# How to distinguish between pinch zoom and click?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom layout to do pinch zoom as parent and a child layout that have many imagview with click event. The problem is when first finger touch the imageview child and second touch other place, it will not zoom but it will just do what is inside click event.

For pinch zoom code I use this:
https://gist.github.com/klarson2/4f737adf7f2577dc0fd09efb85eff3b1

For the click event code:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // primary finger down
                        Log.i("Frag", "actionDOWN");
                        return true;


                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        // non-primary finger down
                        Log.i("Frag", "pointerDOWN");
                        return false; //go to zoom

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // primary finder up
                        Log.i("Frag", "actionUP");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return true; // stay at frag

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        // non-primary finger up
                        Log.i("Frag", "pointerUP");
                        return false;
                }
                return false;


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for some time to check if any other pointer has registered any touch events.
This is the code I use for scaling as well as zooming which works for most of the cases.

```
onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
```

//Let all touch go through scalegesturedetector

```
    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            clickTime = System.nanoTime();
            deltaTime = System.nanoTime();  
        }

        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
            secondPointerDown = true;
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            deltaTime = System.nanoTime();
        }

        // wait for some time (300 - 600 ms) to check for any other pointer.

        if (!secondPointerDown && (deltaTime - clickTime) / 100000.0f > 600) {

            //do click event

        }

        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
            secondPointerDown = false;
            clickTime = System.nanoTime();
            deltaTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
}
```

Comment: ACTION_POINTER_DOWN gets called only when additional finger touches the screen. nice one!

Answer (score -1):

Try this library - 
https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

It includes pan,zoom, double tap

Hope it will help :)

Comment: My pinch zoom work fine the problem is that when the first finger place at imageview it will just do click event. Even though you are trying to pinch zoom.

Comment: for pinch zoom ACTION_DOWN & ACTION_POINTER_DOWN are required, in ACTION_DOWN it will generate click event, u can't zoom with one finger (i.e. ACTION_DOWN).

Comment: I understand that. Now I am using a custom zoom relative layout as parent layout with multiple dynamically created imageView with onTouchListener. I can't zoom properly as if the first finger touch imageView and second finger touch other place it will just do onTouchListener. However if the first finger touch the layout that is the custom zoom layout then touch the child or any other place, it can pinch zoom fine